# Why is my Magento 2 site loading very slowly?

Tags: magento2.3, pagespeed, http-request

The issue I'm experiencing didn't happen until a few days ago. I wasn't sure if it's because of the extensions because I've installed no other extension that has anything to do with speed optimization. The only speed extension I've installed did not cause the issue when I installed it over a week ago.

The symptoms are as follows:

1. First time when I load the page, it literally takes a minute as in, about 60 seconds to load the page.
2. The next time I load that same page (e.g. front page) it loads normally, about 2-3 seconds.
3. However, when I click another link to load a different page, it takes another 60 seconds to load.
4. So the 60 seconds load time only applies to pages that I haven't previously loaded during the browsing session. Pages that I've been before will load like normal. Pages that I haven't been to will take 60 seconds to load for the first time.
5. I have an extension on Chrome that displays page load time and this is the only clue I have. The HTTP request takes over 60,000 ms to complete for the pages that I haven't been into.[image]

So far, I have tried the following, and none of which improves the symptoms:

1. Refreshing the cache. After the cache has been refreshed, the symptoms reset themselves. The pages that loaded normally will now load as if it's the first time loading again, which takes another 60 seconds
2. Disabling and re-enabling the cache, same result as #1
3. Switching to Magento 2 Production Mode.
4. Rebooting the server
5. Cleaning the cache, flushing the cache, re-indexing everything, no changes in the symptoms

Is there anything else I could try to fix it? Any leads would be appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Are you using Redis for page cache?

Comment: No, but I found the problem. It was caused by a third party extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [enabling profiler](https://amasty.com/knowledge-base/how-to-enable-magento-2-profiler.html) and then find out which block or template is taking much time and memory. Try scanning from bottom to top in the profiler.
In most cases, 3rd party extensions are responsible for this.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It was indeed one of the third party extension that caused the bug. Disabling the extension made the site load perfectly fine, like it used to. I was just wondering why it didn't cause immediate problems right after the installation, otherwise I would have found out sooner. Anyways, I'll raise a support ticket to the extension publisher. Thanks again for the advice